# Logs get generated when run from IntelliJ but not from local tomcat server

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea, logging

I have a simple spring boot project and I use log4j2 for logging. When I ran my app in IntelliJ I could see my log files got generated in the specified location but when I packaged it as a war file and deployed it in my local tomcat server, no logs were generated. Any idea?

==========edit============================

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="log.dir">C:\\users\myname\Desktop</Property> 
        <Property name="app.name">myapp</Property>
    </Properties>
 
    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="fileLogger" fileName="${log.dir}/app-info.log" filePattern="${log.dir}/app-info-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true" />
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>
 
        <Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout   pattern="[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n" />
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="com.myapp.mypackage" level="info" additivity="true">
            <appender-ref ref="fileLogger" level="info" />
        </Logger>
        <Root level="debug" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="console" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

This is not exactly my log4j2 config file but mine is just as simple. I have one rolling file appender and I want to log the app info to it. If I run my app in IntelliJ, the log file will get generated and I can see the logs flowing in.

I tried C:/users/myname/Desktop too, it worked for IntelliJ but not for my local tomcat.

The same path worked for my friend, it generated log file on his desktop, but he couldn't think of any specific configurations that he had done.

I also tried setting log.dir to a bunch of nonsense, and put it in my local tomcat server, it actually ran without errors. So I think tomcat is not looking at my log4j2.xml at all?

=================update============================

Ok, I deleted CATALINA_HOME in environment variables and used another version of tomcat and it worked.

I tried tomcat 8.5, 9.0.30 and 9.0.37.
9.0.30 wouldn't run until I set the CATALINA_HOME environment variable; No logs were generated after I set it.

I deleted 9.0.30 and tried 8.5. I changed CATALINA_HOME, set it to the 8.5 folder, and no logs were generated.

I deleted 9.0.30 and used 9.0.37 instead, deleted all CATALINA_HOME variables, and it worked. Logs were generated.

Comment: Please add the Log4j2 configuration to your question. Remember that the working directory (according to the OS) of your server may vary, so relative paths are unreliable.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that the generation path of the log files is not allowed when running in Tomcat. You should look in Catalina logs.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I deleted CATALINA_HOME in environment variables and used another version of tomcat and it worked..

Answer (score 0):

Problems with missing log4j configuration are usually related to the application not finding a log4j config file where you think it should find it. You can add the java parameter `-Dlog4j.debug=true` to get some diagnostics from the application as it searches for a config file. You can also tell it directly to use a particular file with the option `-Dlog4j.configuration=file:/<apath>/log4j.properties`. Running applications within a container such as tomcat adds a further level of complexity to the searched-locations for the configuration.